# Making a link's height the same as the available height inside a navbar in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a `navbar`:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Brand</span>
  <a>I wanna grow</a>
</nav>
```

I want to make the link inside the `navbar` grow to fill the available height (the height of the blue area):

[image: available area]

Why doesn't [this code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjxZYg) work? How can I make it work?

Comment: Why dont you just give the a the same class as span?

Comment: @Squish It doesn't work and it doesn't solve the problem. The idea is knowing why and how in order to solve the same problem in other situations.

Comment: Isn't this what you wanted to achieve? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjxZYg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the percentage value on your anchor tag to work, the parent height of your navbar needs to be explicitly set.

Try something along the lines of:

```
.navbar{ height: 100px; }
```

The only exception to this rule, whereby the height can be figured out implicitly, is the documents root element `<html>`.